# Photograph Copyright Law - Picture transformation

Tags: copyright

I need help regarding some copyright law issues. I live in Canada if that helps with anything..

Lets say I took a picture off the internet of a celebrity and then I mixed up his face with another celebrity and now it only kind of looks like the original picture.

Will the still infringe on copyright law?

Would changing up the background on that picture help too?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the picture isn't yours, then you can't change it in anyway. By changing it, you create what is known as a derivative work - which is a right solely reserved for the copyright holder.

You have two options:

1. Take a picture yourself.

   You took the picture, it's yours. You can do whatever you may please with it.
2. Find a picture with a license

   A license is a contract-like document that expressly provides you with various rights to the picture - including, but not limited to, the right to modify the work, and the right to sell the work. These rights aren't always granted however.

   The most popular license for media works are the Creative Commons works. You can search for such works here: https://search.creativecommons.org